# Trouble with Touch Events in React Native Signature App on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, touch, native, signature

I'm currently working on a signature app using React Native, and I've encountered an issue that seems to be specific to Android devices. When users draw lines near the middle of the drawing board, dots appear on the top left corner of the board. This issue doesn't occur on iPhones.

I've already tried implementing some checks to prevent drawing outside the boundaries of the drawing board, but the problem persists. It seems to happen more when drawing vertical lines in the center of the board.

Here's the code so far:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const SignaturePad = () => {
  const [touchPoints, setTouchPoints] = useState([]);
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState('');

  const handleTouchMove = (event) => {
    const { nativeEvent } = event;
    const { locationX, locationY } = nativeEvent;

    // Limit touch points to be within the boundaries of the square
    if (locationX >= 0 && locationX <= 300 && locationY >= 0 && locationY <= 150) {
      const updatedTouchPoints = [...touchPoints, { x: Math.round(locationX), y: Math.round(locationY) }]; //adding the new point to the rest of the points
      setTouchPoints(updatedTouchPoints);
    }
  };

  const handleSave = () => {
    setNotification(`Touch points saved: ${JSON.stringify(touchPoints)}`);
    setTouchPoints([]); // Reset the doodle after saving
  };

  const handleClear = () => {
    setNotification('');
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View
        style={styles.signaturePadContainer}
        onTouchMove={handleTouchMove}
      >
        <View style={styles.signaturePad}>
          {touchPoints.map((point, index) => (
            <View
              key={index}
              style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                width: 4,
                height: 4,
                borderRadius: 2,
                left: point.x,
                top: point.y,
              }}
            />
          ))}
        </View>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handleSave}>
        <Text>Save</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handleClear}>
        <Text>Clear</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text>{notification}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  signaturePadContainer: {
    width: 300,
    height: 150,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  signaturePad: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: 10,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
});

export default SignaturePad;
```

I suspect there might be something in the way touch events are being registered or processed that's causing this behavior. I've tried debugging and logging the touch event data, but I'm not able to pinpoint the exact cause.

Also, I'm having an issue where if I draw a diagonal line from the bottom right portion of the box, down and left, I can see the line continuing on the top left corner of the box, as though the top left portion of the box is a continuation of the bottom right portion of the box.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue with touch events on Android in React Native? Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to handling touch events would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

While attempting to draw on the board, I've noticed that when I draw near the middle point and certain other areas, dots appear in the top left corner of the board. I'm expecting the drawing to accurately follow my touch without these weird dots.